# why do I get "GitHubActionsReporter error" in jest express.js

Tags: express, jestjs

I started out with jest to test my express endpoints but when running the test I run into:

> Error: Cannot find module './GitHubActionsReporter'

Since the easiest way to reproduce this error is following the documentation, here are the steps I done:

1. `npm install --save-dev jest`
2. Create file sum.js with this code:

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

3. Create file `sum.test.js` with this code:

```js
const sum = require('./sum');
    
test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

4. Add those lines to the package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

5. `npm test`

Comment: Have you exported your module using `module.exports?`

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that this error appears because of the node version is incompatible.

```
v14.0.0 - FAILED
v14.1.0 - FAILED
v14.2.0 - FAILED
v14.4.0 - FAILED
v14.5.0 - FAILED

v14.6.0 - PASSED    
v14.7.0 - PASSED    
v14.17.0 - PASSED    
v14.15.0 - PASSED    
v14.20.1 - PASSED
v15.0.0 - PASSED
v15.14.0 - PASSED
v16.00.0 - PASSED

v16.17.1 - FAILED
```